# Apache Camel request-reply pattern failing over 3 or more micro-services

Tags: apache-camel, microservices

I'm trying to make a [request-reply](https://www.enterpriseintegrationpatterns.com/patterns/messaging/RequestReply.html) return a response over three microservices. So,
1. api 
2. backend service
3. another backend service

However, the message is not making it back to the api (which is blocking) and I get a **timeout issue**. I've troubleshooted the service to service communication and this leaves me with camel as the cause.

I have read [camel in action](https://www.manning.com/books/camel-in-action) and various other sources, but am unsure what the best way to implement a **synchronous transaction over 3 or more micro services**. The EIP patterns usually only accommodate 2 services communicating.

Here is an overview of the camel routes for each service.

**API**

```
rest("/api")
.post("/apply").route()
.inout(APPLY_QUEUE)
```

**Backend Service 1**

```
from(APPLY_QUEUE)
.bean(somebean, "checkApplication")
.to(REGISTER_QUEUE)
```

**Backend Service 2**

```
from(REGISTER_QUEUE)
.bean(somebean, "createApplication")
```

Comment: You are getting timout after how many seconds. You need to set timeout for your rest configuration. Depending on the implementation you are using you need to set the property properly. For examle if you are using jetty then default is 30 seconds and you can change it using continuationTimeout. Check here http://camel.apache.org/jetty.html

Comment: You might need a ".transform().constant("Bye World");" at the end of your backend service 2 to return the response